# How do I rebuild single full text catalog (or why is "rebuild" full text catalog option disabled)

Tags: sql-server, ssms, full-text-search

In SSMS. I have Full Text Catalog defined. If I select "Full Text Catalogs" folder - there is an option "Rebuild All" and it is enabled.
But if I select individual FTC - "Rebuild" option (in context menu) is disabled.

**Question** Why is it disabled? and how do I enable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless there's something weird going on, this state occurs when the catalog is currently being populated.

You can see the current state of the catalog by looking in the Properties window of the catalog.

So... wait until the catalog has finished populating, and then refresh the node in SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

following command can be generated FT properties first page (bottom Catalog Action) -> rebuild catalog

USE [DBNAME]
GO
ALTER FULLTEXT CATALOG [FT Name] REBUILD

after this **Processing notifications** turn to Idle and Rebuild command become enabled